# How to grab news titles from http://alsat-m.tv/category/5/nga-vendi

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to grab titles from **http://alsat-m.tv/category/5/nga-vendi**
but I cant. I have tried with below code. If any one can help me please?Below, I have added to pull titles only like a text and link.This code is working only with http://www.programminghelp.com/  and not with the other web pages, I dont know where the problem is.

```
<?php
  $html = file_get_contents("http://alsat-m.tv/");
  preg_match_all(
     '/<h5><a href="(.*?)" rel="bookmark" title=".*?">(.*?)<\/a><\/h5>/s',
     $html,
     $posts, // will contain the article data
     PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
 );
 foreach ($posts as $post) {
     $link = $post[1];
     $title = $post[2];
     echo "<a href'" . $link . "'>" . $title . "</a></br>";
 }
 echo "<p>" . count($posts) . " posts found</p>";



 $html = file_get_contents("http://www.alsat-m.tv/");

 preg_match_all(
     '/<h5><a href="(.*?)" rel="bookmark" title=".*?">(.*?)<\/a><\/h5>/s',
     $html,
     $posts, // will contain the article data
     PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
 );

 foreach ($posts as $post) {
     $link = $post[1];
     $title = $post[2];

     echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>" . $title . "</a></br>";
 }

 echo "<p>" . count($posts) . " posts found</p>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Why not use the rss feed http://alsat-m.tv/RssFeed

Comment: Can you show me how to use that?

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML; do use an HTML parser.

Comment: $xml = file_get_contents("http://alsat-m.tv/RssFeed");
    $xmlarray = new SimpleXMLElement($xml,true);
    var_dump($xmlarray);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

xml = requests.get('http://alsat-m.tv/RssFeed')
tree = etree.fromstring(xml.content)
root = tree.find('channel')
titles = [x.find('title').text for x in root.findall('item')]
print titles
```

Comment: This is a...java solution?

Comment: Oh my bad haha. I've been reading though python tags all day and assumed "python" when I searched regex. Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, could work for OP, not sure. Might be worth noting in answer what it is so OP can try it. Also a better approach than regexing.